# Adding buttons to UINavigationItem isn't working at all

Tags: ios, swift

I'm sure I've used this pattern before, but something is preventing my from adding UIBarButtonItems to my subclassed UINavigationController

```
// AppDelegate
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds);
    let plainVC = UIViewController();
    plainVC.title = "Plain";
    let explorerNav = ExplorerNavController(rootViewController: plainVC);
    window?.rootViewController = explorerNav;
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible();
    return true
}

//ExplorerNavController
class ExplorerNavController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Dumb", style: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(openSettings));
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(openSettings));
    }

    func openSettings(){
        print("did tap open settings");
    }
}
```

Which just leaves me with:
[image]

I've also tried setting my view controller's navigation item, setting the items in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`. I can style the navigation bar from the same `viewDidLoad` as I set the navigation items, proving that an instance of ExplorerNavController is in fact being created. I'm just not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: i think it will work only if you'll set right and left bar buttons for rootviewcontroller as it was designed to display these buttons per screen not per navigationcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
let leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Dumb", style: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(openSettings))
nav.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(leftBarButtonItem, animated: true)
```